# ASP.NET Core error CS1022 in new clear web project Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have started new test project .net core web from Ubuntu Linux console, and when I am trying to run it, I am getting an error:

```
/tmp/.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs(5,1): 
error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected [/home/alex/projects/test/test/test.csproj]
```

The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.

Ubuntu Linux 18.04
ASP.NET Core 2.1

I have reinstalled SDK full reinstall with `apt-autoremove`, and install again, nothing changed

[image: Screenshot here]

Comment: Mention `test.csproj` file like this, `dotnet run -p test.csproj`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange thing but i have reinstalled SDK again, reboot the machine and after that all is ok.